# Animating the canvas on raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am currently using scaleRaphael on a project to display an SVG map and I am implementing a zoom function.

The zoom is working by using:

```
paper._canvas.changeSize(2 * paper._canvas.w, 2 * paper._canvas.h, true);
```

The resizing is working fine however I cannot get it to animate.

Everywhere I look about animating Raphael talks about animating the elements but I am looking to animate the entire size of the canvas instead.

Comment: Do you need to animate the size of the HTML object that contains the canvas? Or just every SVG object in the canvas at the same time?

Comment: The canvas. I was given a hack way of doing it by looping over 1.0 > 2.0 and increasing the size by a percentage each time but there must be a better way.